# Manually create an empty PDO recordset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, recordset

I have pages where I output a bunch of records in a table.  Occasionally, I have a situation where I want to act as though there are no records.  Is there a way to manually create an empty PDO recordset?  Create the same result as a query that returned no records?

I suppose an alternate to this would be what the most minimal possible (empty result) query I could run that is the least load on the database.

Using PHP 7 and MySQL 5.6

(As to suggestions that I structure the page differently, the alternates are to either use `goto` to jump past the output loop, or wrap the entire loop in a gigantic `if()` statement. I'm aware of these alternative routes. I'm just wondering if there's a ready way to simply pass an empty recordset to my `while( $r = $rs->fetch() )` loop....)

Comment: Does the inside of the loop rely on the data from the query, so wouldn't the data have to at least reflect the result set it would have returned.  At the moment it's a bit difficult to imagine why you need this, so an actual code example may help.

Comment: Just add and to the while loop. Instead of `fetch` use `fetchAll` and use the result as short circuit.

Comment: For example: I have a page that can return a single (specified) record, or all the records.  Running all the records takes a long time -- it's a lot of data and a lot of code churn.  So I modified the page to, by default, just show the record selector plus an "all records" button.  So I'm adding a branch where if neither a single record nor "All" is selected, there should be no data going to the loop.

Comment: @Dharman - fetchAll can be an issue if the fetch has a lot of data. It's not always smart to dump results into an array

Comment: So if there is no data sent to the loop - what does the loop do?

Comment: As long as you have to deal with the user interface, dumping results into an array will never be a problem. A client software will die long before fetchAll() will start causing problems.

Comment: @NigelRen it's effectively a way to bypass the loop without restructuring the page. `If A, $rs = Query1; if B, $rs = Query2; If C, $rs = empty.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that any direct solution would be effectively a *crutch* supporting the initially incorrect architecture.

In a sanely designed web application, a database interaction never ever has any connection to the output. First, the data is collected, then processed and only then the output started. So getting your data into arrays would be a correct solution. Then you can fake an empty array with an empty array.

That said, what you want is directly accomplished by `$rs = new PDOStatement();`

Comment: I understand that a lot of what I'm doing on this old site is a workaround.  It's like the old joke about people from Maine: "If I wanted to go to Redbud, I wouldn't start from here."  *Thank you* for the direct answer.  If I had time I'd rewrite the whole dang thing from scratch, but it's hundreds of pages of unskilled code, half in ASP Classic, and I'm working with what I've got!

Comment: PS -- I learned parameterized queries from your site, @YourCommonSense . Did you know your site is down at the moment?

Comment: Thank you but it seems [it's just for you](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/phpdelusions.net)

Comment: Are you saying there's *never* a disadvantage to just passing results to `fetchAll()` ?  (Yeah, I know... "never' is a loaded word...)

Comment: Only when you have to run a code that doesn't involve a user interaction, such as console script that you run once in a while and that have to dig through big amounts of data. There is a quirk that makes a good rule of thumb: as long as you don't bother to run an *unbuffered* query, you can always use fetchAll().

Comment: I suppose I could also make my loop something like `while( $rs && $r = $rs->fetch() )`, then my "empty" could simply involve setting $rs to False.  But that just looks ugly to me.  When I *do* resort to a hack, I try to use the cleanest hack I can muster....

Comment: For future reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: I am rather worried about the site availability. Can you please check it today, if it's still down for you?

Comment: I can access it on my iPhone, but not my work computer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what and why you are trying to do. It looks like you are looking for a "dirty hack" to bypass some code, instead of modifying it. However - In PHP 7 you can just define an anonymous class with a `fetch()` method, which will always return `false`:

```
$rs = new class() {
    public function fetch() {
        return false;
    }
};

while( $r = $rs->fetch() ) {
    echo "This shouldn't be printed.";
}
```

Comment: Not the best direct answer, but I can see this structure being potentially useful in other situations

Comment: @StephenR While `$rs = new PDOStatement();` is shorter and just fine as a "crutch", I don't know if it's documented anywhere, what `fetch()` would return in this case. It seems that any method is returning `false`. Which is fine for `fetch()` - But if you (for example) want to run `fetchAll()`, you will get (again) `false`, though your code might expect an array. With my solution you would just write another method `fetchAll()` returning an empty array.

Comment: Interesting point.  It would seem that the result of `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` would be "falsy" at any rate, which would respond as expected as a `while` loop test

Comment: Looking into the actual PHP stubs, `fetch()` says "In all cases, <b>FALSE</b> is returned on failure."  No similar statement for `fetchAll()`

Comment: [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php): "An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or **FALSE** on failure." However - `(new PDOStatement())->fetchAll()` also returns **FALSE**.

Comment: Right. fetchAll on a non-resultset sounds like a failure to me -- which gives False.  So the `new PDOStatement()` solution relies on the "false on failure", which is indeed documented.

Comment: Of course if I'm doing `fetchAll()` this entire discussion is a moot point!  So the `fetch()` result is the only one that matters in this context :-)